# Setting the scroll rate on a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, scroll

I have a bootstrap list group (with angularjs) of a few hundred items. The list is set to be scrollable (dont want to have a giant page). However if you click or use the scroll wheel, it will move by a fraction of an item.

How do you set the scroll rate such that it moves by an item at a time (moves by 40px - the hieght of the item div). I suspect I am using the wrong control for this...

css:

```
.list{
   max-height: 200px;
   overflow:scroll;
}
```

html:

```
 <div class="form-inline list" style="">

     <div class="list-group  " >
          <a  class="list-group-item " ng-repeat="thing in things">
              <div style="height:50px;"> Some tall stuff</div>
          </a>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: How many items are in this list?

Comment: a many dozens to hundreds

Comment: I answered what may be a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839487/auto-scroll-to-next-anchor-at-mouse-wheel/25839854#25839854.