# Auto-Scroll to next anchor at Mouse-wheel using AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

It's a question similar to one asked before here - [Auto-Scroll to next anchor at Mouse-wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839487/auto-scroll-to-next-anchor-at-mouse-wheel)
Except, I'm looking for a solution in **AngularJS**.

Quoting the question -

> I have 5 anchors on my html page. Is there any way that the page scrolls automatically to the next anchor (#) by a single Mouse-wheel scroll? Is there a way that it happens regardless of the anchor's name? just to the next anchor.

An animation is also required.

I've already explored [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) which doesn't support animation.
Also, there is [`angular-scroll`](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll) which I'm unable to trigger on a *scroll event.*

Comment: all u need is to rewrite that solution to directive