# Automatically scroll to closest anchor point when between

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, anchor

I was looking for a script that automatically scrolls to the closest anchor point e.g. when between pages.

Just like on this website http://cihadturhan.com/

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: No can't find something close to that on the website. Seems to be selfmade

Comment: I think you are looking for this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839487/auto-scroll-to-next-anchor-at-mouse-wheel

Comment: Close to that. I'm looking for one where you have full control of the scrolling but it scrolls automatically to the center of the next page, when you are between those two. Just like on the website I linked http://cihadturhan.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hacked together a fiddle which behaves like the page you mentioned.

I used the following snippet to check when a scroll event ended:

```
$.fn.scrollStopped = function(callback) {
  var that = this
  var $this = $(that);
  $this.scroll(function(ev) {
    clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
    $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback.bind(that), 250, ev));
  });
};
```

Then I compared the offsets from the sections with the window offset (in order to find the closest).

Here is the demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/cz8gz8cd/

(The code could need some improvement)